# how to "zoom-out" background-cover image?

Tags: html, css

basically, my background cover image is "zoomed-in" when it is in the display width of a laptop device - screen 1025px to 1280px. I have started my project on smartphone device - 320px to 479px, and the background image cover is perfect, the way I want it to be. however, now have worked to the laptop screen device it has decided to "zoom-in" to my cover image. could one of the reasons why it is doing this is I might need to adjust this specific image taken in Singapore?
CSS

```
[![.singapore {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("img/SINGA1.JPG") top center;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.singapore .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: none;
}][1]][1]
```

html

```
<section class="singapore">
    <!--sinapore-->
    <div class="inner">

        <div class="content">

            <h1>Singapore</h1>

            <p>Beautiful landscapes, friendly locals and an unforgettable paradise</p>

            <button>View Album</button>

        </div>
        <!--CONTENT-->

    </div>
    <!--INNER-->
```

[image]

Comment: `background-size: cover` as the name suggests "covers" the entirety of the element with the image. The aspect ratio of the element will dictate how much of the image can be visible.

Comment: what do you want the behavior to be on the larger screen?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `background-size: contain;` property.

`cover` will always find a way to fill his owner.

`contain`, on the other hand, will always preserve image integrity by set it's largest side equal the largest owner's side.

Comment: Thanks, it actually solved the issue. We can also pass background-size in percentage to customize it ```background-size: 50%```